# Combine two opus stream in node.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js, opus

I am attempting to combine multiple audio streams that have opus encoding into one. I have tried this

```
let audio = listenerConnection.receiver.createStream(users.first(), { end: "manual"});
        let audio2 = listenerConnection.receiver.createStream(Array.from(users.keys())[1], {  end: "manual"});
        
        audio.on("data", (data) => {
            console.log(data);
        })
        audio2.on("data", (data) => {
            audio.push(audio2);
        })
        speakerDispatcher.once('finish', () => {
            console.log("Speaker")
            speakerConnection.play(audio, {type: "opus"});
        })
```

However instead of combining the steam it sort of push it in a place which cause a kind of discontinuity. Audio2 becomes very disjointed. Do you know a way to combine audio together in a sort of way for opus that make sense so that like the amplitude of the program changes rather than forcing things together.

Comment: Hi Shreyas. It might improve your chances of getting a useful answer to your question if you edit your question to make what you're looking for a bit clearer. Some things that weren't clear to me: (1) what changes you want in the amplitude of your joined stream. 2) what you don't like about the result that you're getting, i.e., what you mean by forcing things together and kind of discontinuity. Good luck!